# Python Web Scraping (edX)

Tags: python, edx

I am trying to download a course on edx. Please refer to the following readme (https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl/blob/master/README.md). I installed Anaconda for Windows (I am running Windows 10 in Parallel Desktop).

In the last step, I typed in the following command: C:\edx-dl-master\edx-dl-master>edx-dl -u user@user.com COURSE-URL and upon entering my edX password, get the following:

Building initial headers for future requests.
Getting initial CSRF token.
Found CSRF token.
Logging into Open edX site: https://courses.edx.org/login_ajax
Extracting course information from dashboard.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in 
_run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\edx-dl.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 1011, in main
    for selected_course in selected_courses}
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 1011, in <dictcomp>
    for selected_course in selected_courses}
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\edx_dl.py", line 186, in get_available_sections
sections = page_extractor.extract_sections_from_html(page, BASE_URL)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\parsing.py", line 403, in extract_sections_from_html
for i, section_soup in enumerate(sections_soup, 1)]
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\parsing.py", line 403, in <listcomp>
for i, section_soup in enumerate(sections_soup, 1)]
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\parsing.py", line 392, in _make_subsections
for i, s in enumerate(subsections_soup, 1)]
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\edx_dl\parsing.py", line 392, in <listcomp>
for i, s in enumerate(subsections_soup, 1)]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

I am new to Python, and am not sure what remedial measures I can take.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
git clone https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl/blob/master/README.md
```

Install git first.